# Cannot insert data to sqlite database; why not?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to save data to sqlite database but it does not work.

```
// Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement =  "INSERT INTO INCOMPLETECLAIM ( provideName,claimAmount, serviceType, receipentName, serviceStart, serviceEnd) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;                
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
                //sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [serStatus UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                NSLog(@"testtt");

              sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [prName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
              sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [prAmnt UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
              sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [gTps UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
              sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 5, [gRecipent UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
              sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 6, [gSSFSS UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
              sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 7, [myString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are any errors reported?  Where is your database located?  (If you attempt to alter a DB included in your project without first moving it to a writeable dir, the updates will not "take".)

Comment: Find out what the [error message](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) is and add it to your question.

Comment: I notice that you start your index values in bindText with 2 for some reason.  This doesn't seem right.  The first `?` would be index 1, and the max index should be 6.

Comment: And you never actually execute the sqlite3_stmt (with sqlite3_step).

Comment: it does not show any error report

Comment: The first column of table is id and auto increment ,for this case i did not use index 1

Comment: The numbering of the index values corresponds to the count of "?" characters in the statement.  Not (directly) related to the declared columns in the table.  If you don't specify a "1" then nothing replaces the first "?".

Comment: Plus, as I said, you have to actually execute the statement.  Simply preparing it isn't enough.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the statement using sqlite3_step as follows:

```
sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
```